# Regular Expression to remove a copyright

Tags: python, regex

I need to remove the year from a copyright. The copyright can be in the following forms:

```
2011 Company --> 'Company'
Company 2011 --> 'Company'
2011 1 Company 2 --> '1 Company 2'
1 Company 2 1944 --> '1 Company 2'
```

How would I remove the 4-digit copyright and get the company only (note that the company may include numbers in its name).

So far I've tried [0-9]{4}, but have had trouble forming it into a re search.

```
>>> a=re.search('[0-9]{4}',a)
>>> a
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10527b780>
>>> a.match(0)
>>> AttributeError: match
```

Comment: If there can be a 2 between the company name and the number, what else can there be?  Line breaks?  Do you know the company name before the regex needs to be run?  Can you assume anything about the year, e.g., 'it's going to between 1900 and 2020?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '2011 Company'
>>> removed = re.sub('(^\d{4})|(\d{4}$)','',s).strip()
>>> print removed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def removeYear(inputStr):
    pattern1 = re.compile(r'^\d{4,4}\ (.*)')
    outputStr = re.sub(pattern1, r"\1", inputStr)

    pattern2 = re.compile(r'(.*)\ \d{4,4}$')
    fixedStr = re.sub(pattern2, r"\1", outputStr)
    print '-->'+ fixedStr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    removeYear('2011 Company')
    removeYear('Company 2011')
    removeYear('2011 1 Company 2')
    removeYear('1 Company 2 1944')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{4}
```

means 4-digits, or you can write like this in order to trim white spaces:

```
\s*\d{4}\s*
```

Is this what you want?